# toggle something with if

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make something pop up if the if property = true, this works now, but the problem is that it keeps running over and over again, so it just goes up and down.

does anyone know how to make sure it keeps checking but it only executes the function once?

this is what i have now:

javascript:

```
    var characterTop = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top")
    )
    var characterLeft = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left")
    )
  
    if (characterTop > 200 && characterLeft > 700) {
      document.getElementById("win").classList.toggle("active")
      
      {stopMoveLeft();}
      {stopMoveRight();}
      {stopMoveDown();}
      {stopMoveUp();}
    }
}, 1000);
```

html:

`<div id="win"></div>`

css:

```
#win {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 600px;
    transition: all 500ms linear;

}

#win.active {
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Looks like you have already solved it.

Comment: So what is not working exactly?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To maximize your chances of getting help can you please ask a more specific question? What is the problem exactly? Although it can be challenging at first, taking the time to ask precise question will for sure help you increase your understanding.

Comment: you are going to do this check 1000 times per second, which seems a bit extreme.

Comment: @epascarello if the if statement = true it keeps toggeling the class and i have no idea on how to make sure it only toggles it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number in `setInterval` (in your case, `1`), is in milliseconds, not seconds — `setInterval(/*...*/,1)` is the functional equivalent of `while(true){/*...*/}`. Also, `setInterval` doesn't return anything useful, and only runs once (when you define it).

Keeping that in mind, here is a revised version of your code:

```js
setInterval(function () {
  var characterTop = parseInt(
    window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top")
  )
  var characterLeft = parseInt(
    window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left")
  )

  if (characterTop < 500 && characterLeft < 500) {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("active")
  } else return
}, 1000);
```